# Calculate a surface integral

Tags: calculus

I have $Y=(x,y,z): x^2+y^2-9z=0, z \le 9$ and $F(x,y,z) = (x,y,z)$ and if I want to calculate both the fluid integral and the surface integral, how do I do that? It is a infinite paraboloid. with radius $\sqrt(3)$ I guess.

I don't need help to calculate the curl, **just the boundaries** in the both of the integrals

Comment: It is closed from above by $z \leqslant 9$, so intersection on $(x,y)$ plane gives circle with radius 9. They are your boundaries.

Comment: but in the fluid integral, it should be $\int_{dY} F \cdot N = \int_0^{2pi} F \cdot dr$ and the surface integral $\iint_Y curl \cdot N d = \int_0^{\pi} \int_0^{\sqrt(9)} curl F \cdot NdS$ ? or?

Comment: sorry don't understnad? =)

Comment: You have some geometrical figure in space, bounded by $x^2+y^2-9z=0, z \le 9$. So it is  paraboloid cropped from top by plane $z=9$. Projection of intersection of paraboloid and plane gives circle $x^2+y^2=9^2$ on plane $(x,y)$. Is everything clear so far?

Comment: yes! I understand.so my previous comment, I meant 2pi not 1pi

Comment: Yes. And radius is 9 not $\sqrt{9}$. Ok?

Comment: yes it is 3z :)

Comment: but really, what is the different between $ds$ and $dr$? and sometimes I have noticed that some functions with the curl and stuff, are not equal. what does that mean?

Comment: Without context is difficult to give general answer. Usually $ds$ means surface or path, while $dr$ often is used with polar coordinates. So, everything depends on source/author you work with.